# Java Development Kit (JDK) from ftp?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, jdk

I need to download specific JDK version but from console in Linux. I have not lynx/elinks etc linstalled. Where can i download Java Development Kit (JDK) from ftp ?

Comment: What linux distribution do you use? Many distributions have jdk packages in their repositories.

Comment: Debian - Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You can also use wget to download files over http.

To install Sun JDK, do the following...

Add this line to /etc/apt/sources.lst

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ maverick partner
```

Then *sudo-apt-get install sun-java6-jdk* will install it.

Assuming Ubuntu 10.10, here...

Comment: I can not use sudo (permissions). I just need to get (wget) jdk zip/tgz/bz2.